# Black lines in animation and image render due to motion blur

Tags: animation, motion-blur

I am very new to blender, and this is my first time animating in blender. I have followed the BlenderGuru youtube tutorial for the doughnut and have just finished.
However when I render my image or animation with motion blur turned on I get black bars replacing my shadows. when I turn motion blur off and render again, it looks fine.

Motion Blur off:
[image]

Motion Blur on:
[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Silly question; Why are you applying motion blur to a static scene?

Comment: Because im trying to animate it. the balck bars show up in both the animation and image renders

Comment: A wild guess: AMD GPU?